# WPF, passing variable to converter inside data template

Tags: wpf, xaml, parameters, converters

I assume this is possible but not sure how to do it. I need to pass the value of a class level variable to a converter, from within side a data template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ResponseItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <StackPanel.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Key"/>
                    <Binding Path="CurrentLanguage"/> 
                </MultiBinding> 
            </StackPanel.Visibility>

            <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The 'Key' value exists on the response item for the data template so this gets passed correctly, whereas the CurrentLanguage is a class variable and I can't get that to pass properly to the converter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies, this is what I needed to use in the end:

```
 <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentLanguage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the converter as a resource, which you have, you can access it in the code behind. Once you have the converter you can then set a property on it.

```
var myVisConverter = (VisibilityConverter)window.Resources["VisibilityConverter"];
myVisConverter.CurrentLanguage = ...
```

**EDIT** Ok, if you're trying to get access to the parent DataContext from within the DataTemplate, there's a couple of options. Easiest is to name the control with the correct DataContext, then bind to that control like so...

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentLanguage" ElementName="nameGivenToElement" />
```

Josh Smith wrote an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx) with more ways of getting inherited DataContexts.

Comment: Hi Cameron,
Thanks for the reply, I'm tyring to use the MVVM pattern, so avoid using the code-behind. Just need a way to access the CurrentLanguage variable in the view model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binding object as follows:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static local:DataObject.MyData}" />
```

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c94682e5-ad16-42f9-973f-fd7588a9c0b5.